# Multiple to_timestamp() transformation in SELECT

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am currently having a varchar *tm* column, that stores timestamps such as: `'15.11.2021 11:07:27'`

The datestyle is currently set to `ISO,MDY`

How can I transform that varchar using SELECT value in order to preserve its format?

If I use `to_timestamp(tm, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS')::timestamp without time zone` I still get it in other format `2021-11-15 11:07:27`

I also tried to do double to_timestamps, but then an error `function to_timestamp(timestamp with time zone, unknown) does not exist` appears.

So the question is: Is there any way to convert from varchar type "15.11.2021 11:07:27" to timestamp type 15.11.2021 11:07:27 using select statement?

[DbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=49098b3ba172f1857bc933595d30d17c)

PS. Even though I used it in DBFiddle, I cant change datestyle on the target server

Postgres version 13.5

EDIT: also, if I use `cast(tm as timestamp)` I receive  `date/time field value out of range: "15.11.2021 11:07:27"` error.

Comment: A `timestamp` does not have any format. So once you have converted your  string value to a proper timestamp, it lost all formatting. Any format you _see_ is applied by the application displaying the `timestamp` value. So you need to check the SQL tool you are using if you can influence the formatting of `timestamp` values. The `datestyle` config property is only used by `psql` for the output if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thank you for your quick reply. Does it imply then that my future inserts will be of the desired (as I initially specified) format even though they are not shown like I want?

Comment: A (real) `timestamp` value does not have any format. So if you insert proper timestamp values no format will be applied. A format is only applied if the value is **displayed**. But as long as the column stays a `varchar` nothing will be changed.

Answer (score -2):

You could try using:
`CONVERT(varchar, timestamp, 103) AS YOUR_VALUE`
This way you would convert timestamp without changing its original form.

Comment: Postgres does not have a `CONVERT` function, so this answer does not apply.

Comment: Oups he updated it after my response